How to insert gap between columns in table
I want to create this table layout. How can I add a gap between columns, similar to the design? I used border-collapse: separate, but then the border in tbody are hard to adjust, so I changed to collapse. Is this a good approach for creating this table, or should I not use ? I tried to find the answer here, but coulnd't find any satisfying answer

I created this table


.table-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

[data-module=data-table] {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 16px 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

[data-module=data-table] thead {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

[data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #242424;
  position: relative;
}

[data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type th {
  color: #242424;
  /* Desktop/Fira Sans/H2 Regular */
  font-family: "Bree Serif";
  font-size: 28px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 130%;
  /* 36.4px */
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 0 32px;
  height: 5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type th {
    /* Mobile/Fira Sans/H2 Regular */
    font-family: "Bree Serif";
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 130%;
    /* 26px */
  }
}

[data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type th:first-of-type {
  color: #242424;
  /* Desktop/Fira Sans/Copy 1 Regular */
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 150%;
  /* 27px */
  background-color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type th:first-of-type {
    /* Mobile/Fira Sans/Copy 1 Regular */
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

[data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type th.highlighted {
  background-color: #006366;
  color: #fff;
}

[data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #242424;
}

[data-module=data-table] thead .table-header-content {
  color: #242424;
  /* Desktop/Fira Sans/Copy 1 Regular */
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 150%;
  /* 27px */
  text-align: left;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-module=data-table] thead .table-header-content {
    /* Mobile/Fira Sans/Copy 1 Regular */
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

[data-module=data-table] thead .table-header-content h3 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 130%;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-module=data-table] thead .table-header-content h3 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr td,
[data-module=data-table] tbody tr th {
  position: relative;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr td>.cell-content,
[data-module=data-table] tbody tr th>.cell-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 4px;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 144px;
  text-align: center;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr td::after,
[data-module=data-table] tbody tr th::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #242424;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr td {
  border-left: 1px solid #242424;
  border-right: 1px solid #242424;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr:last-child td::after {
  display: none;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #242424;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #242424;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody th>div {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody th>div>div {
  text-align: left;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody th>div>div p:first-of-type {
  color: #242424;
  /* Desktop/Fira Sans/Copy 1 SemiBold */
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 150%;
  /* 27px */
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-module=data-table] tbody th>div>div p:first-of-type {
    /* Mobile/Fira Sans/Copy 1 SemiBold */
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 150%;
    /* 24px */
  }
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody th>div>div p:last-of-type {
  color: #515151;
  /* Desktop/Fira Sans/Hinweistext */
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 150%;
  /* 21px */
  color: #515151;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-module=data-table] tbody th>div>div p:last-of-type {
    /* Mobile/Fira Sans/Hinweis */
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 150%;
    /* 18px */
  }
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody td.highlighted-column {
  border-left: 2px #006366 solid;
  border-right: 2px #006366 solid;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody td.highlighted-column:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
<div class="table-container">
    <table data-module="data-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Leistungsbereich</th>
                <th>BASIS</th>
                <th class="highlighted">OPTIMAL</th>
                <th>PLUS</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">
                    <div class="table-header-content">
                        <h3>Table Headline</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li>Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod</li>
                            <li>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Column Headline</p>
                            <p>Hinweis text</p>
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <div class="cell-content">-</div>
                </td>
                <td class="highlighted-column">
                    <div class="cell-content">
                        <div class="checkmark">✔</div>
                        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
                        <p>Hinweis</p>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="cell-content checkmark">✔</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Column Headline</p>
                            <p>Hinweis text</p>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <div class="cell-content">-</div>
                </td>
                <td class="highlighted-column">
                    <div class="cell-content checkmark">✔</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="cell-content checkmark">✔</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Column Headline</p>
                            <p>Hinweis text</p>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <div class="cell-content">-</div>
                </td>
                <td class="highlighted-column">
                    <div class="cell-content checkmark">✔</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="cell-content">-</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>




Remove the border-collapse: collapse; from the [data-module=data-table]  css.

Or you can change from collapse to  separate.

Problem I get when I put seperate is styling borders around columns

the reason why you find hard time to fix this layout is because this is not for table (we are not back in the '90s). You should work with divs. A flex layout will do what you want very quickly and there are tons of examples out there. Tables are only to represent tabular data not for creating layouts

use borders of the same color as the background and give them a proper width (half the required width) and use box-shadow as border instead...

Actually this is not a pure table which is being displayed in the attached image in the question. So, I think instead of using <table> you can utilize div and use CSS or Bootstrap to style it.
I have used <div> with custom CSS. I hope this will satisfy your needs. You can set font-family, font-size, and font-style according to your desire.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Table</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" />

  <style>
    section {
      padding: 20px 30px;
    }
    
    .header {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 10px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #a3a2a2;
    }
    
    .table {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      gap: 10px;
    }
    
    .border-bottom {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb8b8;
    }
    
    .border {
      border: 1px solid #bbb8b8;
      border-radius: 7px;
    }
    
    .border-green {
      border: 2px solid #006366;
      border-radius: 7px;
    }
    
    .bg-gray {
      background-color: #bbb8b8;
      border-top-right-radius: 7px;
      border-top-left-radius: 7px;
      padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    }
    
    .bg-green {
      background-color: #006366;
      border-top-right-radius: 7px;
      border-top-left-radius: 7px;
      padding: 0 0 0 20px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .w-100 {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .p-10 {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .table-col {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .align-center {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100px;
    }
    
    .align-start {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: start;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100px;
    }
    
    .m-0 {
      margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    }
    
    .text-small {
      font-size: small;
      color: #a3a2a2;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="w-100">
        <span>Leistungsbereich</span>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-gray w-100">
        <h1>BASIS</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-green w-100">
        <h1>OPTIMAL</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-gray w-100">
        <h1>PLUS</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h2>Table Headline</h2>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      </p>

      <ul>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-col w-100">
        <div class="align-start p-10 border-bottom">
          <h3 class="m-0">Column Headline</h3>
          <span class="text-small">Hinweistext</span>
        </div>

        <div class="align-start p-10 border-bottom">
          <h3 class="m-0">Column Headline</h3>
          <span class="text-small">Hinweistext</span>
        </div>

        <div class="align-start p-10">
          <h3 class="m-0">Column Headline</h3>
          <span class="text-small">Hinweistext</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-col w-100 border">
        <div class="align-center p-10 border-bottom">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-minus" style="color: #babcbf"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="align-center p-10 border-bottom">
          <p class="m-0">Column Text Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <span class="text-small">(Hinweistext)</span>
        </div>

        <div class="align-center p-10">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-minus" style="color: #babcbf; margin-bottom: 5px"></i>
          <p class="m-0">Column Text Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <span class="text-small">(Hinweistext)</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-col w-100 border-green">
        <div class="align-center p-10 border-bottom">
          <i class="fa fa-check" style="color: #006366"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="align-center p-10 border-bottom">
          <p class="m-0">Column Text Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <span class="text-small">(Hinweistext)</span>
        </div>

        <div class="align-center p-10">
          <i class="fa fa-check" style="color: #006366; margin-bottom: 5px"></i>
          <p class="m-0">Column Text Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <span class="text-small">(Hinweistext)</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-col w-100 border">
        <div class="align-center p-10 border-bottom">
          <i class="fa fa-check" style="color: #006366"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="align-center p-10 border-bottom">
          <p class="m-0">Column Text Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <span class="text-small">(Hinweistext)</span>
        </div>

        <div class="align-center p-10">
          <i class="fa fa-check" style="color: #006366; margin-bottom: 5px"></i>
          <p class="m-0">Column Text Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <span class="text-small">(Hinweistext)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>




If you remove the border-collapse: collapse;, you should then be able to use a selector like [data-module=data-table] tr:first-of-type td.highlighted-column to add the top border (with border-radius as necessary) to complete the card look.
It looks like you're doing something similar on another column.
:last-of-type on the tr to add a rounded border to the bottom.

A workaround (!) is to duplicate the content and hide the unnecessary content with visibility: collapse;, and then set border-collapse: separate; to the upper table that contains the menu in question, like so:


.table-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

[data-module=data-table] {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 16px 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

[data-module=data-table] thead {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

[data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #242424;
  position: relative;
}

[data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type th {
  color: #242424;
  /* Desktop/Fira Sans/H2 Regular */
  font-family: "Bree Serif";
  font-size: 28px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 130%;
  /* 36.4px */
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 0 32px;
  height: 5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type th {
    /* Mobile/Fira Sans/H2 Regular */
    font-family: "Bree Serif";
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 130%;
    /* 26px */
  }
}

[data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type th:first-of-type {
  color: #242424;
  /* Desktop/Fira Sans/Copy 1 Regular */
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 150%;
  /* 27px */
  background-color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type th:first-of-type {
    /* Mobile/Fira Sans/Copy 1 Regular */
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

[data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type th.highlighted {
  background-color: #006366;
  color: #fff;
}

[data-module=data-table] thead tr:first-of-type::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #242424;
}

[data-module=data-table] thead .table-header-content {
  color: #242424;
  /* Desktop/Fira Sans/Copy 1 Regular */
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 150%;
  /* 27px */
  text-align: left;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-module=data-table] thead .table-header-content {
    /* Mobile/Fira Sans/Copy 1 Regular */
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

[data-module=data-table] thead .table-header-content h3 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 130%;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-module=data-table] thead .table-header-content h3 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr td,
[data-module=data-table] tbody tr th {
  position: relative;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr td>.cell-content,
[data-module=data-table] tbody tr th>.cell-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 4px;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 144px;
  text-align: center;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr td::after,
[data-module=data-table] tbody tr th::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #242424;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr td {
  border-left: 1px solid #242424;
  border-right: 1px solid #242424;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr:last-child td::after {
  display: none;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #242424;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #242424;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody th>div {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody th>div>div {
  text-align: left;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody th>div>div p:first-of-type {
  color: #242424;
  /* Desktop/Fira Sans/Copy 1 SemiBold */
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 150%;
  /* 27px */
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-module=data-table] tbody th>div>div p:first-of-type {
    /* Mobile/Fira Sans/Copy 1 SemiBold */
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 150%;
    /* 24px */
  }
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody th>div>div p:last-of-type {
  color: #515151;
  /* Desktop/Fira Sans/Hinweistext */
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 150%;
  /* 21px */
  color: #515151;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  [data-module=data-table] tbody th>div>div p:last-of-type {
    /* Mobile/Fira Sans/Hinweis */
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 150%;
    /* 18px */
  }
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody td.highlighted-column {
  border-left: 2px #006366 solid;
  border-right: 2px #006366 solid;
}

[data-module=data-table] tbody td.highlighted-column:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
<div class="table-container">
  <table data-module="data-table" style="border-collapse: separate;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Leistungsbereich</th>
        <th>BASIS</th>
        <th class="highlighted">OPTIMAL</th>
        <th>PLUS</th>
      </tr>
      <tr style="visibility: collapse;">
        <th colspan="4">
          <div class="table-header-content">
            <h3>Table Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
              <li>Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="visibility: collapse;">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div>
            <div>
              <p>Column Headline</p>
              <p>Hinweis text</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </th>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-content">-</div>
        </td>
        <td class="highlighted-column">
          <div class="cell-content">
            <div class="checkmark">✔</div>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
            <p>Hinweis</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-content checkmark">✔</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div>
            <div>
              <p>Column Headline</p>
              <p>Hinweis text</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </th>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-content">-</div>
        </td>
        <td class="highlighted-column">
          <div class="cell-content checkmark">✔</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-content checkmark">✔</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div>
            <div>
              <p>Column Headline</p>
              <p>Hinweis text</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </th>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-content">-</div>
        </td>
        <td class="highlighted-column">
          <div class="cell-content checkmark">✔</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-content">-</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table data-module="data-table">
    <thead>
      <tr style="visibility: collapse;">
        <th>Leistungsbereich</th>
        <th>BASIS</th>
        <th class="highlighted">OPTIMAL</th>
        <th>PLUS</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">
          <div class="table-header-content">
            <h3>Table Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
              <li>Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div>
            <div>
              <p>Column Headline</p>
              <p>Hinweis text</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </th>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-content">-</div>
        </td>
        <td class="highlighted-column">
          <div class="cell-content">
            <div class="checkmark">✔</div>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
            <p>Hinweis</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-content checkmark">✔</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div>
            <div>
              <p>Column Headline</p>
              <p>Hinweis text</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </th>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-content">-</div>
        </td>
        <td class="highlighted-column">
          <div class="cell-content checkmark">✔</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-content checkmark">✔</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div>
            <div>
              <p>Column Headline</p>
              <p>Hinweis text</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </th>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-content">-</div>
        </td>
        <td class="highlighted-column">
          <div class="cell-content checkmark">✔</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-content">-</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



